# C＃Oracleからデータを取得し挿入

Tags: c#, oracle, datagridview

開発環境Visual Studio2017
言語c#

#### 実現したいこと

注文情報が入ったCSVファイルを読み込みレイアウト編集をして出力したい

1. 注文情報CSVファイルを読み込みとオラクルのデータから商品データ読み込み
2. 上記の二つを使いレイアウト編集
   *補足：読み取り時JANコード（15列目にデータがあります。）編集時JANコードは無し（代わりにカラーとサイズが４列目、７列目に存在します）
3. DataGridViewに出力

１の注文情報CSVファイルから読み込んだデータにはJANコードがあるのですが、カラー、サイズのデータはなく注文情報CSVファイルのレイアウト編集時にJANコードではなくカラー、サイズの列を作りたいと考えています。そのためにoracleからJANコードに紐づいた二つ（カラー、サイズ）を取得したい
接続するところまでは下記のURLを参考にしてやってみました。

[C# Oracleに接続してselectするサンプル](https://itsakura.com/csharp-oracle)

#### 解決したい問題

２の編集するために注文情報CSVファイル（JANコード）とoracle（カラー、サイズ）のデータを紐づけてコード内の作成した列に投入するところです。（カラムAカラムBの列）

例（読み込み時レイアウト）

```
NO,名前,,,,,,JANコード
A1,B2,,,,,,,jan1
A2,B2,,,,,,jan2
```

例（変更後レイアウト）
*例をシンプルにするために４項目ですが、後ろに挿入ではなく前後関係は完全にバラバラです。

```
NO,名前,,カラー,,サイズ,,,,,
A1,B1,,c1,,d1,,,,,
A2,B2,,c2,,d2,,,,,
```

レイアウト作成コード

```
DataTable table = new DataTable("ResultTable"); // 結果用テーブル作成
table.Columns.Add("からむ1", typeof(String));
table.Columns.Add("からむ2", typeof(String));
table.Columns.Add("からむ3", typeof(String));
table.Columns.Add("カラムA", typeof(String));
table.Columns.Add("からむ4", typeof(String));
table.Columns.Add("からむ5", typeof(String));
table.Columns.Add("カラムB", typeof(String));

DataTable csvtable = ReadCSV('CSVデータファイルパス'); // CSVデータ取得

foreach(DataRow csvrow in csvtable.Rows) // コピー処理
{
    DataRow dtrow = table.NewRow();
    dtrow["からむ1"] = csvrow["カラム1"];
    dtrow["からむ2"] = csvrow["カラム2"];
    dtrow["からむ3"] = csvrow["カラム3"];
  //dtrow["カラムA"] = "JANコードからカラー";
    dtrow["からむ4"] = csvrow["カラム4"];
    dtrow["からむ5"] = csvrow["カラム5"];
  //dtrow["カラムB"] = "JANコードからサイズ";
    table.Rows.Add(dtrow);
}
```

Comment: CSVとオラクルは全く同じ行順序で並んでいるのでしょうか？ 一般的にデーターベースエンジンは並べ替えを行わない限り、順序は保証されていないはずですが。

Comment: どのような意図で、どんなネット資料を見たのですか？　そして、何が判らなかったというのでしょうか？
「呼び出し方を教えていただきたい」との事ですが、何から何を呼び出すのでしょうか。

何であるかが誰にでもわかるように具体的に説明してください。
"何か判らない"ことだらけで、理解不可能です。

Comment: @Fumu7  ご指摘ありがとうございます。　CSVファイル内のJANコードに該当するカラーとサイズをオラクル内から抽出して表の空欄部分に挿入することを指していました。説明不足。しておりまして申し訳ございませんでした。質問編集致しましたのでご確認お願いします。

Comment: ご返答ありがとうございます。CSVとオラクルは全く同じ順序で並んでおりません。csv内のJANコードで表しているデータをオラクルから抜くことができないかと思っていました。@sayuri

Comment: 流通小売業だとJANコードを基にDBから商品名・単価などを取得するPLU(Price Look Up)という処理が一般的で、それと同様の処理を`foreach`の各行データに対して行えば良いと思われます。ただし、質問記事の例の「CSVファイル(何番目がJANコード?)」・「読み込み時レイアウト」・「変更後レイアウト」の間に、どんなデータや変換ロジックが関わっているかが示されていないように見えます。それだと具体的な回答を得るのは難しいのでは？

Comment: @kunif  ご指摘ありがとうございます。確かに情報が不足しておりました。PLUという処理が一般的なものになるのですね。PLUに関して初めて聞くものだったので確認してみます。質問編集致しましたので確認お願いいたします。

Comment: 例えばこの辺の記事 [SQL 入門 (DMLの基本形式:SELECT)](https://www.shift-the-oracle.com/sql/select.html), [【SQL】3分でSELECT文を完全マスター!データ取得の基礎から応用まで!](https://www.sejuku.net/blog/72964) に書かれているSQL文に相当する内容を記述出来るくらいのデータベース内容の情報が必要でしょう。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSVとOracleと、それぞれ別のDataTableに読み込んでおき、[LINQ to DataSet](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/linq-to-dataset)を用いて結合するのはどうでしょうか。[結合結果からDataTableを構築する](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/creating-a-datatable-from-a-query-linq-to-dataset)ことが可能ですので、最終目標のDataGridViewに表示することもできるはずです。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。試してみます。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございました。動作正常にいたしました。