# DataTable if(カラム＝カラム)について

Tags: c#

開発環境: Visual Studio 2017　c＃

複数のDataTable内のカラム名が同じだったら処理をするというIf文はどのように書けばよろしいでしょうか。
oracleのカラム
カラー,サイズ,品名,バーコード

csvのカラム
バーコードのみ

Resultのカラム
カラー,サイズ,品名
だった場合、foreachのなかでoracleのバーコードカラム＝csvのバーコードカラムにして処理を進める？
書き方があっているのか微妙ですが前後でしていること含めて書いてます。
分かりにくい思いますが、回答よろしくお願いします。

```
//CSVデータのDataTable
DataTable csvDT = new DataTable();
//OracleデータのDataTable
DataTable oracleDT = new DataTable();
//結果用のDataTable作成
DataTable ResultDT = new DataTable("ReasultDataTable");
//ResultDTからユニークリスト作成
DataTable dtDistinct = ResultDT.DefaultView.ToTable(true,"Barcode");
//ユニークリストを使ってSQLを書く
DataRows[] rows =dtDistinct.select("品名,カラー,サイズ,Barcode");
//SQLを投げてOracleDTで受け取る
//oracleDTとcsvDTをぶつけてresultDTに書き込む
foreach (DataRow r in csvDT.Rows)
{
    if(r["Barcode"] == oracleDT.Columns["Barcode"])
    {
     //csvDtの品番　=oracleDTのバーコード
     ResultDT["品番"]=r["品番"];
     //csvDtのサイズ=oracleDTのバーコード
     ResultDT["サイズ"]=r["サイズ"];
　　　//csvDtのカラー=oracleDTのバーコード
     ResultDT["カラー"]=r["カラー"];
　　　}
}
```

Comment: 各テーブルの構成・内容と、それぞれの間の関係・連携(何と何が同じで、どのデータをどうするか等)の情報を具体化・整理すれば、自分で気付けるのでは？ それらを追記してみてください。

Comment: @kunif  記述方法がいまいち分からなくてifのなかで(csvDT["Barcode"]==oracleDT["Barcode"])という書き方をしたのですが、[ ]は使えませんと出てしまい調べたのですが、当てはまる物を探せませんでした。

Comment: その書き方をするなら、`csvDT/*のバーコードデータのカラム*/`は`r["Barcode"]`でしょう。[Item\[String\]](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.data.datarow.item?view=net-5.0#System_Data_DataRow_Item_System_String_) そして`if`で判定するのではなく、`LINQ`で取り出すわけです。[DATATABLE から LINQ で行を取り出す](https://rksoftware.wordpress.com/2016/04/16/datatable-%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89-linq-%E3%81%A7%E8%A1%8C%E3%82%92%E5%8F%96%E3%82%8A%E5%87%BA%E3%81%99/)

Comment: 確かにr["Barcode"]ですね。どの記事もLINQでのやり方が書いてあったのですが、文の役割があまり理解できなかったのif文で書いた方がイメージがつくなと思いifで書こうとしておりました。 @kunif

Comment: [C＃Oracleからデータを取得し挿入](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/71491/c-oracle%e3%81%8b%e3%82%89%e3%83%87%e3%83%bc%e3%82%bf%e3%82%92%e5%8f%96%e5%be%97%e3%81%97%e6%8c%bf%e5%85%a5#comment79280_71491) でコメントし伝わっていたと思っていました。カラムを一致させるのではなく、それぞれのテーブルの行と行を突き合わせて一致する行を探す必要があります。

Comment: @sayuri  正常に動作はしたもののできたというよりも、出来てしまった感じで理解が出来なかったので if文でカラムの行データが＝だったら結果用の行に差し込む的な文がないかと思いましてお伺いしております。

Comment: @亀レオン そうであれば、出来てしまったコードを提示して「foreachで書き直すとどうなるか」と尋ねるのも一つの手です。現状、質問文からは回答としてマークされたものの採用されずに別アプローチを試しているかのようにしか読み取れませんでしたので（何を求めているのかあいまいでした）。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LINQの知識・経験があるわけでは無く、検索結果からの推測ですが。

この辺の記事を参考にすると、`//結果用のDataTable作成`以後は以下のように書き直しになるのでは？ (結果テーブルの列が`品番`(Barcode?)なのか`品名`なのか曖昧ですが)
前回 @sayuri さん紹介記事の中の最初の [例](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/creating-a-datatable-from-a-query-linq-to-dataset#example)
[LINQでの内部結合・外部結合](https://qiita.com/H-Takayama/items/0e0a962f9ebc59547e4d) の [内部結合の方法](https://qiita.com/H-Takayama/items/0e0a962f9ebc59547e4d#%E5%86%85%E9%83%A8%E7%B5%90%E5%90%88%E3%81%AE%E6%96%B9%E6%B3%95)
[内部結合の実行](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-inner-joins)
[左外部結合の実行](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-left-outer-joins)

```
var query =
    from csv in csvDT
    join db in oracleDT
    on csv.Barcode equals db.Barcode
    select new
    {
        Barcode = db.Barcode,  // 品名なら最後の行に Name = db.Name
        Size = db.Size,
        Color = db.Color
    };

DataTable ResultDT = query.CopyToDataTable();
```

---

**コメント対応調査**

この辺の記事を見ると上記ソースは以下のようになるのかもしれません。
[LINQ to DataSet でのクエリ](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/queries-in-linq-to-dataset)
[ジェネリック メソッド Field および SetField (LINQ to DataSet)](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/generic-field-and-setfield-methods-linq-to-dataset)
[How do I get this Linq query with custom join into a DataSet?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16574125/9014308)

DataTable指定には`.AsEnumerable()`を付ける
カラムへのアクセスには`["カラム名"]`か`Field<型>("カラム名")`/`SetField("カラム名", 値)`を使う

こんな感じでしょうか。

```
var query =
    from csv in csvDT.AsEnumerable()
    join db in oracleDT.AsEnumerable()
    on csv.Field<string>("Barcode") equals db.Field<string>("Barcode")
    select new
    {
        Barcode = db.Field<string>("Color"),  // 品名なら最後の行に Name = db.Field<string>("Name")
        Size = db.Field<string>("Size"),
        Color = db.Field<string>("Color")
    };
```

あるいは、何処かの変数/カラム/DataTableやその定義で`public`指定が必要なものが抜けているとか。
[”～はアクセスできない保護レベルになっています”と表示された場合の解決法](https://allmoreidea.hatenablog.com/entry/2018/06/30/112231)

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。join db in oracleDTの箇所でアクセスできない保護レベルというエラーが出てしまいました。

Comment: それはOracleそのものの設定や属性か、oracleDTを作る時の何かかもしれませんね。実際にOracleと接続するのではなく、csvDTと同様にテキストやcsvから仮のDataTableを作って試してみてはどうでしょう？ それでも発生するなら正確なエラー文言全部を追記してみてください。仮に作ったものなら動くのなら、それは新規の質問にしてもらえば良いと思います。